# I need to change the value of a boolean in an array in react redux

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Hey everyone I need to change the value of a boolean in an array in react redux. In the default state it is set to false and I need to set it to true. I am trying to change the state with an onclick event but I cant seem to do it any help I would be happy. When I click on the button reserved it still set to false and I need it set to true so I can make changes.

here it is at the start
`

```
export const getRockets = createAsyncThunk(
  'rocketSlice/getRockets',
  async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/rockets').then(
      (data) => data.json()
    );
    const rocketApiInfo = response.map((rocket) => {
      const rockets = {
        id: rocket.rocket_id,
        rocketName: rocket.rocket_name,
        description: rocket.description,
        flickrImages: rocket.flickr_images,
        reserved: false,
      };
      return rockets;
    });
    return rocketApiInfo;
  }
);
```

`my reducers`

```
const rocketsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'rockets',
  initialState: {
    rockets: [],
    status: '',
    loading: true,
  },
  reducers: {
    reserveRocket(state, action) {
      const newState = state.rockets.map((rocket) => {
        if (rocket.id === action.payload) {
          return { ...rocket, reserved: true };
        }
        return rocket;
      });
      return { ...state, rockets: newState };
    },

    cancelReservation(state, action) {
      const newState = state.rockets.map((rocket) => {
        if (rocket.id === action.payload) {
          return { ...rocket, reserved: false };
        }
        return rocket;
      });
      return { ...state, rockets: newState };
    },
  },
```

`
the function

```
  const reservedhandler = (e) => {
    if (reserved === false) {
      dispatch(reserveRocket(e.target.id));
    } else {
      dispatch(cancelReservation(e.target.id));
    }
  };
```

reserved is undefined so maybe that is the problem. But i am not sure how to fix it. Thanks guys

Comment: ive been trying to fix it still nothing yet ...

Comment: I tried to map over it again in the reservedhandler function still doesnt work

Comment: use [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) to determine what the state looks like after the change. It looks as though your reducer is not modifying the state correctly, you may need to spread value of `newState`  rather than assigning it to the `rockets` value. [Maybe this will help](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#reducers-and-immutable-updates)